# How to pass var-args to a Python script command using a bash-script?

Tags: bash

I have a Python script that accepts an argument like:
`python3 my.py --something --something-else -i [...]` so I can call with one or more arguments to `-i`.

I want to wrap this all up in a bash script as the other parameters don't change... I can see how to do it with a single argument but not an arbitrary number of them.

Is there an easy way?

I want to basically have `bash mypy.sh 1 2 3 4...`

I'm not a linux user and my googling didn't through an obvious answer - I can loop the parameters but the script I'm calling want's a single list, not to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the full set of command-line arguments with `"$@"`.

```
python my.py --something --something-else -i "$@"
```

The quotes should be considered *mandatory*; never use `$@` alone. This allows you to preserve arguments as originally quoted, like if you call was

```
bash mypy.sh 1 "2 3" 4
```